# How to change JQuery Mobile list search filter bar to data-mini="true" style?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery Mobile 1.2.0 and would like my [search filter bar](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-search.html) to be of style data-mini="true". How can I do this?

The search filter bar `<input type="text"` is dynamically created by JQuery Mobile so I can't just add the attribute `data-mini="true"` to my markup. Instead I have to insert it via traversing the DOM using JavaScript as you can see below. This did not work despite trying to call a variety of [refresh](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html) and [create](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/docs-forms.html) methods to get JQuery Mobile to re-enhance the search filter bar's input field.

Here's the beginnings of the code I used:

```
$("#my-page").on("pageinit", function(event) {
    $("input[placeholder='Email']").each(function (index, element) {
        element.setAttribute("data-mini", "true");
        /* What goes here to make my search filter bar display in mini mode? */
    });
}
```

Comment: where is the code that puts it on the page dynamically... like code behind or another script...

Comment: @RobinRieger I updated the question to clarify that JQuery Mobile dynamically creates the search filter bar not my code.

Answer (score 0):

You are manually creating a search filter but JQM already does it with a simple attribute:

```
data-filter = "true"
```

but it ONLY applies to  elements, therefore I would do something like this.

```
$("#my-page").on("pageinit", function(event) {
    $('#my-page').find('ul').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-mini','true');
    $(this).attr('data-filter','true');
});
```

If you are working with  as you should, this will work.